# Create an activity opening transition like this one

Tags: android, animation

Do you think there is a way to create an activity opening animation (in anim or transition) that looks like this one (just that the activity must not be opened from an image)
https://youtu.be/Ne2uHFi_e_M?t=41s

If yes, could you help me to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Anything is possible with code.

Comment: @JordanSeanor Sure, you're right there lol. But might you know how to realize it?:)